# Django redirect user to app based on permission and group

Tags: django, python-3.x

Say i have a django project which have 4 apps 1 app is for logging in

project urls:

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf import settings

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^', include('Login.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

settings:

```
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/'
```

login app urls:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^login/$', auth_views.login, name='login'),
    url(r'^logout/$', auth_views.logout, {'next_page': '/'}, name='logout'),
]
```

now say i have 3 apps based on user type i.e. Admin, Team Lead, Worker
so i want to redirect user based on their type of employment.

how can i achieve this ?
any help is appreciated

Answer (score 2):

I guess that you will manually add/edit the user groups.
That can be done from django admin panel.
Here is the group/permission django docs: [Permissions and Authorization](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/auth/default/#permissions-and-authorization)

This is what I did:
I've created an index view in order to get the user group and redirect to the respective view that you want.

**So, index view in views.py:**

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

@login_required
def index(request):
    group = request.user.groups.filter(user=request.user)[0]
    if group.name=="employees":
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('worker'))
    elif group.name=="teamLeader":
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('teamLeader'))
    elif group.name=="admin":
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('adm'))

    context = {}
    template = "index.html"
    return render(request, template, context)
```

**And urls in urls.py:**

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
from app import views as app_views
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^login/$', auth_views.login, name='login'),
    url(r'^$', app_views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^employees/$', app_views.employees, name='employees'),
    url(r'^teamLeader/$', app_views.teamLeader, name='teamLeader'),
    url(r'^adm/$', app_views.adm, name='adm'),
]
```

**In settings.py**

```
LOGIN_URL = '/login'
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/'
```

Is this what you want to do?